# if the event is recurring, i do not want to want to re render the data

Tags: reactjs

I have a drop down which is consisting of one value.If the same value is selected for the second time in the drop down i do not want to re render the page again.

```
form = (
    onChange={(e) => this.onP(e)}/>
);

onP = (event) => {
    this.setState({
    selectedItem: event.value
});
```

If I select the same drop down again then whatever the data already written(in the form) should remains the same

Answer (score 1):

You could check the value of your `selectedItem` before updating the state of your component :

```
if (this.state.selectedItem !== event.value) {
    this.setState({selectedItem: event.value});
}
```

Comment: This is what i have changed but its not working,not able to track kindly help me

onP = (event) => {

        if (this.state.selectedItem !== event.value) {


            this.setState({


                selectedItem: event.value


            });

        }

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough code here for me to help you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well, you want to update state based on the previous value and React recommends using the callback API of setState if you attempting to do something of that kind.

```
onP = (event) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
     if(prevState.selectedItem !== event.value){
         return {selectedItem: event.value}
     }
});
```